# How do I catch specific error (timeout 504) in Power Apps

Tags: powerapps

In power apps, I have a flow that runs on a button press and sometimes based on what the user has asked for in the app the flow can time out (takes longer than 2 minutes to respond). I want to set a variable at this point to Timeout. Is there some way to detect the type of error in onError in the APP? something like.

`if(error.type = 504, set(status, "Timeout"))`

Any help would be appreciated.